Selecting from DataFrames with mixed dtypes MultiIndex columns returns data with wrong type
I have DataFrames organized like this:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
        columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Time','A','B'],[1,2]]),
        index=[0,1,2],
        data=[[0,1,2,3,4,5],[10,11,12,13,14,15],[20,21,22,23,24,25]],
        dtype=float)

Now I want to select all of the 'B' columns and their respective level 1 column index for a given row index. One way to to that is
df.loc[2,'B']

And I get this:
1    24.0
2    25.0
Name: 2, dtype: float64

So far, so good.
Now let's mix the datatypes in the DataFrame.
import datetime
times = pd.date_range("2018-01-01", periods=3, freq="h").values
df[('Time',1)] = times
df[('Time',2)] = times
df = df.sort_index(level=1,axis=1)

Now my DataFrame has datetime objects in the 'Time' columns:
df.dtypes

A     1           float64
B     1           float64
Time  1    datetime64[ns]
A     2           float64
B     2           float64
Time  2    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object

Now let's try the same selection as above:
df.loc[2,'B']

But this time I get:
1    24.0
2    25.0
Name: 2, dtype: object

That is, the dtype has been changed to object!
But wait, there's another way to select the data I want:
df.loc[2,('B',slice(None))]

and this time I get:
B  1    24.0
   2    25.0
Name: 2, dtype: float64

which is the correct answer.
Why this difference? And why does it happen only when dtypes are mixed?

df.loc[2, ['B']] or df['B'].loc[2] also return the correct dtype, but not df.loc[2]['B'].
I believe it has to do with the internal order in which the axes are sliced.
Indeed df.loc[2] is an object Series, therefore slicing first the rows, then the columns makes it object.
# slicing the columns first
df['B'].loc[2]

1    24.0
2    25.0
Name: 2, dtype: float64

# slicing the rows first
df.loc[2]['B']

1    24.0
2    25.0
Name: 2, dtype: object

The first step determines the final dtype:
# slicing the columns first
# yields a float dtype
# since all columns are float
df['B'].dtypes

1    float64
2    float64
dtype: object

# slicing the rows first
# yields an object dtype
# since a row is a mix of dtypes
df.loc[2]

A     1                   22.0
B     1                   24.0
Time  1    2018-01-01 02:00:00
A     2                   23.0
B     2                   25.0
Time  2    2018-01-01 02:00:00
Name: 2, dtype: object

